# Regex match two words in a string

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match (look for) two words in a string which is as follows:

```
Mac OS X/10.11.5 (15F34); ExchangeWebServices/6.0 (243);
```

I want to match (true) if we see "`Mac`" AND "`ExchangeWebServices`" but the characters between the two words would be unknown/random. Can someone help me with the regex syntax?

Thanks!

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: `Mac.+ExchangeWebServices`

Comment: Its on an ADFS server. Looks like .+ or .* will work. What would be the difference between the two?

Comment: @user3813723 You really need to use a regex tutorial ... Also `.*` matches *zero* or more character(s) but `.+` matches *one* or more character(s).

Comment: @SeanBright thanks. So `Mac.+ExchangeWebServices` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @user3813723 You are welcome .. good, You've found your pattern .. use it and enjoy `;-)`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will match exactly the words "Mac" and "ExchangeWebServices" with anything else between them:

```
\bMac\b.*\bExchangeWebServices\b
```

Regex 101 Example: https://regex101.com/r/sK2qG1/4

Answer (score 5):

This is a simple regular expression can be get by

```
/^Mac.+ExchangeWebServices/
```

We are assuming 'Mac' and 'ExchangeWebServices' are two different words separated by some character.

you can follow the link to learn more of regular expressions
[Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736/3323444)

Answer (score 2):

With this regular epression you can find the words and anything in between even if the words are longer than the words in the regular expression:

```
(Mac).*?(ExchangeWebServices).*?
```

It would find this string:

```
Mac OS X/10.11.5 whatever text in between (15F34); ExchangeWebServices/6.0 (243);
```

So, if you write the words without the end (ExchangeWebServ):

```
(Mac).*?(ExchangeWebServ).*?
```

It would find both strings:

```
Mac OS X/10.11.5 whatever text in between (15F34); ExchangeWebServices/6.0 (243);
```

And:

```
Mac OS X/10.11.5 whatever text in between (15F34); ExchangeWebServ/6.0 (243);
```

If you need to match exact words you'll need to use `\b` as mentioned in the answers above.

Answer (score 0):

`(apple|banana)` will ALSO match "*applebanana*"... try this instead:

```
(\bapple\b|\bbanana\b)
```

That will match either the whole word *apple* or the whole word *banana*, but not *applebanana* or *bananaapple*