# Checking for partial matches in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to come up with a solution to check if the values in column E are partially contained in column B. However, as can be seen in the picture below, the code I have written yields incorrect results sometimes (the first one is a false negative - it is indeed correct).

[image]

The code I have used is:

=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(LOWER(E2), LOWER(B2))), "ok", "check")

Are there any improvements I can make to further refine the code?

Here's an extract of the Google Sheets document I am using:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WYSvUYeSn9maqU8W-RpvSolSl6vFrt8t6wX7QNPbP10/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: SEARCH is already not case sensitive so need to use LOWER. Second, without seeing data as a table it is hard to see the problem. Your values in E might have trailing spaces

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have edited the question and included the link to a GSheets document.

Comment: Your formula in `Cell_D3` is looking at *B2*, *C2* which are headers & `SALAMANDER` in *C8* also has a trailing space(just as the above person quoted)

Comment: Your formula is working, however I have noticed there are some samples with multiple strings to search like in cell C52 & C53. What should it return if only one of it is found in the column B?

Comment: @Logan, in that case, if all elements of the string, which are separated by commas, are found on column, B it should return OK as well.

Comment: @djur i have posted an answer, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(REGEXMATCH(lower(B3:B),lower(SUBSTITUTE(C3:C,",",".+"))),"ok","check"))
```

##### Result:

[image]

##### Explanation:

Using `REGEXMATCH()` this is the same as the `SEARCH()` function however it is case sensitive so we have to use `LOWER()`. And based on your condition it has to match all words if there are multiple words which are separated by comma. For that we use the `SUBSTITUTE()` to replace the comma with ".+" so it has to match all the words.

##### References:

- [REGEXMATCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en)
- [SUBSTITUTE()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094215?hl=en)
- [Regex match two words in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644579/regex-match-two-words-in-a-string)

Comment: This works like a charm. Thank you also for the explanation, it does help me understand the code much better.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad your concern is resolved. @djur